# Integer overflow wrapping and calculation

Tags: integer, integer-overflow

Im a beginner to programming and i am learning about C integer overflows, i am finding it hard to grasp the concept of the output of a integer overflow and i have a few questions:

- What is wrapping in integer overflows and is there a common mathematical procedure which is done too display a big number in integer overflows?
- I was reading on Wikipedia and it said **"The most common result of an overflow is that the least significant representable digits of the result are stored; the result is said to wrap around the maximum (i.e. modulo a power of the radix, usually two in modern computers, but sometimes ten or another radix)."** and **" When an arithmetic operation produces a result larger than the maximum above for an N-bit integer, an overflow reduces the result to modulo N-th power of 2, retaining only the least significant bits of the result and effectively causing a wrap around."**

I don't really understand what is being said here at all, what does "the least significant representable digits of the result are stored" mean and "the result is said to wrap around the maximum (i.e modulo a power of the radix" and lastly what does it mean for "an overflow reduces the result to modulo nth power of 2, retaining only the least significant bit", Can someone please explain this to me in depth with examples and i don't understand this at all.

The last time i asked a question about this it got closed down as a duplicate and the duplicate link to the so called "duplicate" question did not help me at all or answer my question because it was so vauge and not in depth as i wanted my understanding to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any positive whole number N, when representing mathematical integers using straight binary notation, subtracting 1 from a number whose last N bits are zero will yield a number whose last N bits are all 1, and adding one to a binary number whose last bits are all 1 will yield a number whose last N bits are all zero, independent of the value of any upper bits.  Further, for any N, because the last N bits of the number zero will be zero for any N, subtracting 1 from zero will yield a number whose last N bits are all 1.  Thus, the value -1 is effectively an infinite number of 1 bits.

Because it would be impractical to use an infinite number of bits to hold the value -1, computers generally use a convention whereby all bits to the left of the most significant represented bit in a signed number are assumed to hold the same value as that bit.  This has the effect of causing the value of the most significant bit to behave as a negative number whose magnitude as the same as for an unsigned value.

In languages like Java, or in the dialect of C invented by Dennis Ritchie, a computation involving signed integers will be processed as though the representable bits were computed, and then the value of the upper bit is "sign extended" through an infinite number of upper bits.  Because some computers behave differently, the Standard allows implementations to behave in arbitrarily different fashion.  Some "clever" implementations like gcc interpret this as an invitation to behave nonsensically when integer overflows occur even when running on platforms where integer overflow would behave predictably.